# Moving Elements In A Stack

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I have a Stack that's implemented using an array, it takes 6 character as an input from the user (Small Case and Upper Case Letters). Then transfers the Upper Case Letters to another stack (Removing it from the original one)

I have the following code, it moves elements along the stack to the top then pops it once it's at the top and pushes it onto the new array.

```
for (int i = P->top(); i >= 0; i--)
{
  if (P->data[i] >= 65 && P->data[i] <= 90)
  {
    for (int j = i; j < P->top(); i++)
    {
      char swap = P->data[i + 1];
      P->data[i + 1] = P->data[i];
      P->data[i] = swap;
      stackT.push(P->pop());
      i = P->top();
    }
  }
}
```

I should have another array with Upper Case letters and the original one with lowercase letters.

It gets weird results, sometimes it completely destroys the original array, sometimes it only transfer one Upper Case element and messes up the others.

I'm just out of ideas.

And yes, the problem is limited to the use of Stacks and no it's not a Homework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A minimal, complete, compilable code would be helpful.  Unless you are just looking for suggestions, in which case I'd say use a debugger or try using unit tests.

Comment: You have asked a non-question. Start small. What happens to your stack if it only contains a single element and this code runs? Answering that may lead you to why you have the problem you described.

Comment: Code clarity: change `>= 65` to `>='a'`, and `<=90` to `<='z'`. Not everybody has the ASCII chart memorized.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess around with moving things *inside* the stack.
(I expect that the purpose of this exercise is that you use only stack operations, and a stack can only be modified at the "top" - anything else is not a stack.)

Instead use a third, temporary, stack.

```
stack original = .. whatever ...;
stack uppercase;
stack other;
// Classify the contents
while (!original.empty())
{
    char c = original.top();
    original.pop();
    if (std::isupper(c))
    {
        uppercase.push(c);
    }
    else
    {
        other.push(c);
    }
}
// Restore the non-uppercase stack.
while (!other.empty())
{
    original.push(other.top());
    other.pop();
}
```

Comment: What about the size of the temp stack that I'm going to create?

Comment: I have no idea what your stack interface looks like. How did you determine the size of the "uppercase" stack?

Comment: Using a Stack implementation that I made -> https://github.com/saa-d/DS_Stack/blob/master/lib/myStack.h